# SharePoint 2010 custom display form like publishing page?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, page-layout, sharepoint-list

I want to display a list item in a different detail page, not dispform.aspx, not in modalbox. Page must be inherit site masterpage, layout page and must be in portal sitemap like publishing page.

Breadcrumb must be like this:
Company Intranet > Announcements > Product request formm updated!

Is there any way for do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chaning the System Master to publishing master page will render all the forms with Same UI as you see in Home page.

You can change it in this Location **http://yousite/_layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx** You have to do this in site where you what to see this change.

To Prevent the popup forms Go to **List Settings->Advanced Settings** and turn off the Dialog.

Also to change default Form of List you have multiple forms

1. Create a [New Form](http://kalsing.blogspot.com/2006/11/create-custom-list-form-for-sharepoint.html) (Link is for 2007 same applies for 2010 as well) in SharePoint Designer and Associate it to the List.
2. Use Infopath to create a [Custom Form](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=320)
3. Develop a new Webpart that will do Add Edit etc and Add it to the Default Forms.

Comment: I know how I can turn off modal dialog and changing masterpage. Actually I want to show item data in different view, not standart item detail view. Think a simple product detail page. SharePoint shows all informations about product in generic view. But I want to show product image, price and content in different zones on page. How can I do this?